# Rolling, Tallying, Average Dice Rolls

Tags: c#

I'm in need of some help with this dice rolling program I am creating for one of my courses. I am to have the user input a number of rolls, calculate the total of each dice throw tallying each thrown, display this and calculate the average. I'm stuck on how to actually calculate the total of each dice thrown and how to display that. This is actually done without arrays or methods, so I understand the program looks really redundant and long, but that was the purpose of it.
Any help is so so appreciated. I'm really stumped on this being a super amateur ^^"

Comment: Please use an array and loops. Do not repeat the same code.

Comment: I see no need for a method or an array unless you need to keep track of how many times a 2, 3, 4 etc. is rolled, all the `rX` variables are unnecessary. Could you not simply use one variable named `sum` and simply add the rolled value to the `sum` with each iteration? It appears irrelevant “what” number was rolled; you only need to add the total of each roll to the `sum`. Then, after the `for` loop is done, divide the `sum` by the `numberOfThrows`… You may be overcomplicating what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could probably explain the actual problem in greater detail. The posted code is not the best way to do it, but I see nothing obvious functionally wrong. If you are looking for code review, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x;
        int[] r = new int[13];
        for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
            r[i] = 0;

        Console.Write("How many times would you like to throw the dice: ");
        int numberOfThrows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        x = numberOfThrows;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThrows; i++)
        {
            int d1 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int d2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int sum = d1 + d2;
            
            r[sum]++;
            
         }
            
        for (int i=2; i<13; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(r[i]);
        Console.ReadKey();
        
    }
```

Comment: So the purpose of this lab was to NOT use arrays or methods. The outcome should look something like:

Comment: How many throws would you like: 600 (the user puts in a number of throws)

2: 5
3: 31
4: 56
5: 69
6: 91
7: 105
8: 84
9: 68
10: 48
11: 32
12: 11
The average of the rolls is: 7.001666666667 (the program should tally how many rolls and find the average of the sum of rolls)